# Input in C using string

Tags: c, string, input

How can i take input in of multiple lines from keyboard till i don't encounter #
for example my input is this

```
A = B = 4    
C = (D = 2)*_2     
C = D = 2 * _2    
F = C - D    
E = D * _10    
Z = 10 / 3    
#
```

scanf only take input till space so how can i insure that my string take input till #

Comment: How much C do you know - you haven't come across any input functions? And you don't mean the C++ `string` do you?

Comment: It's good practice to attempt to solve your own problems before posting. Also, if this is homework, you should note that as well.

Comment: I can't see any efforts from you to solve this problem. -1. Tip to any problem of that kind. Ask yourself how would you do it if you were the computer, and tell him to do exactly the same things.

Comment: I know how to take input of a single line but as soon as a i click enter my code jump to next step. So if you can solve this it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can use scanf() to find what you are looking for / not looking for.  If you are new, I would suggest making the first character of each line a marker character and insisting on the input being a particular style.  Parsing can get complicated quickly.

(By marker I mean, if the line starts with '#' then end the loop.  If the line starts with something like '$' then process the following line.)

**edit after previous submitter comment - You should have the reader inside a while loop, reading each line independently, and checking for the termination character each time.